# Can the WPF ResourceDictionary return a new instance for each request

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

We're using ResourceDictionaries to store layout information for our app. The lazy initialisation is great because we can grab the required layout for an element only when that element is created. The problem is that each element gets the same instance from the `ResourceDictionary` for each one that shares the layout (or the same one if it goes out of scope and is needed later).

We could store templates in the dictionary then it doesn't matter if they're shared but we have quite a nice system going if it wasn't for this caching behaviour.

Is there a way to change this behaviour of the dictionary or am I going to have to write my own class which creates items from the XAML on demand?

Comment: Is your `ResourceDictionary` that contains the items within another `ResourceDictionary`? `x:Shared="false"` will not work in that situation

Comment: @JRoughan What's wrong with its *caching behaviour*? I don't understand, why do you want to turn it off? Can you illustrate your issue a little bit more, please? It's just for my curiosity. Thank you.

Comment: I want to turn it off because it's not holding templates, it's holding actual framework elements that should be instantiated based on the supplied key

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Yeah, I read the docs for that and I'm not in the failure scenario(s) it specifies (i.e. it's a direct resource in a ResourceDictionary, not a merge dictionary or a dictionary within a style within a ResourceDicionary entry)

Answer (score 4):

Try applying x:Shared="false" attribute. Each resource should then get seperate copy.

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried that, sorry. No effect from what I observed

Comment: @JRoughan it should work cause it is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx)

Comment: @Jehof Indeed it _should_ but I wouldn't be here if it _did_ :) There may be something else specific to my scenario but I haven't found what it is yet. There are a lot of moving parts here to isolate the simplest case. Will update the question if I can reproduce the behaviour in an example